# pandas groupby two columns and multiply two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe grouped by like this;

```
                      price      quantity   vat
date      brand
20-Jun-13 Reebok         7.0         8    2.2
          Adidas        12.0         3    3.8
          Campus         2.5        38    4.2
          Woodlands     23.0         9    7.2
          Boot           3.2        35    3.3
21-Jun-13 Reebok         7.0         6    2.2
          Adidas        12.0        23    3.8
          Campus         2.5        18    4.2
          Woodlands     23.0        29    7.2
          Boot           3.2        15    3.3
22-Jun-13 Reebok         5.0         2    3.5
          Adidas        10.0         5    2.8
          Campus         2.0        50    3.5
          Woodlands     25.0         4    6.5
          Boot           2.5        10    2.8
```

How do I groupby `'date'` and `'brand'` and multiply `'price'` and `'quantity'` to calculate sales?

I've tried;

print `data2.groupby(['date','brand'])['price'] * ['quantity']`

I would like to calculate the total sales by date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your data is already grouped by date and brand, so why not just create a new sales column:

```
df['sales'] = df['price'] * df['quantity']
```

Comment: `data2.groupby(['date'])['sales'].sum()` This makes sense Andy?

Comment: That gets the daily sales, whilst groupby brand would do get total sales by brand :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'

Comment: @phasselmann you can multiply Series (as in the above, where do is a DataFrame) not SeriesGroupBy objects... Please ask as a new question!