# How do I return this groupby calculated values back to the dataframe as a single column?

Tags: pandas, apply

I am new to Pandas. Sorry for using images instead of tables here; I tried to follow the instructions for inserting a table, but I couldn't.

Pandas version: '1.3.2'

[Given this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXL6W.png) with Close and Volume for stocks, I've managed to calculate OBV, using pandas, like this:

```
df.groupby('Ticker').apply(lambda x: (np.sign(x['Close'].diff().fillna(0)) * x['Volume']).cumsum())
```

The above gave me the correct values for OBV as
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ7Qm.png).

However, I'm not able to assign the calculated values to a new column.

I would like to do something like this:

```
df['OBV'] = df.groupby('Ticker').apply(lambda x: (np.sign(x['Close'].diff().fillna(0)) * x['Volume']).cumsum())
```

But simply doing the expression above of course will throw us the error:

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

What am I missing?

How can I insert the calculated values into the original dataframe as a single column, df['OBV'] ?

I've checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object) so I'm sure I should use apply.

[This discussion looked promising, but it is not for my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280651/pandas-groupby-two-columns-and-multiply-two-other-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) for remove first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df['OBV'] = df.groupby('Ticker').apply(lambda x: (np.sign(x['Close'].diff().fillna(0)) * x['Volume']).cumsum()).droplevel(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, @jezrael, but it caused the following error:

ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.